# What is wrong with MySQL create table command?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is wrong with my SQL create table command?

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
(
team_name VARCHAR(250) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
duration_of_play DATE,
duration_of_play_in_team DATE NOT NULL,
position CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(position) 
);
```

Comment: Well, for one it lacks an error

Comment: auto increment for varchar ? you may want an `iduser_info` as auto increment and set this as primary key.

Comment: Also the PK must include the auto_increment column.

Comment: even though (logically) PK is used on auto_increment column it is not a must (technically)

Comment: `position` being a `char(100)` rather than a `varchar` is a bit of a mystery also - do all users really have a position exactly 100 characters long?

Comment: if you literally mean `duration` how are you going to store duration in a date column which is a point in time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the `AUTO_INCREMENT` modifier on a column with datatype `INT`. What do you mean by trying to increment the team name automatically? It seems like you may have accidentally combined two fields, it should be:

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
team_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
duration_of_play DATE,
duration_of_play_in_team DATE NOT NULL,
position CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY(position) 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is at this line `team_name VARCHAR(250) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL`
VARCHAR could not be AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT is not allowed for VARCHAR datatype in MySql, Use following query

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
(
team_name VARCHAR(250)  NOT NULL ,
duration_of_play DATE,
duration_of_play_in_team DATE NOT NULL,
position CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(position) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Varchar can't be auto incremented. Add an id for you table.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
(
id_user_info int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
team_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
duration_of_play DATE,
duration_of_play_in_team DATE NOT NULL,
position CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```